# DateTime format conversion to string ignores AM/PM

Tags: datetime, .net-4.0, string-formatting

I am trying to convert DateTime object to string using formatting but due to some strange reason, it ignores AM/PM. It would just take the magnitude of the Hour in the object.

I am using the following format:

```
StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");
```

and

```
String.Format("0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", StartDate);
```

I don't think that there is a difference between the two, but just wanted to give it a try. If I pass a value **4/28/2012 6:00:00 AM** or **4/28/2012 6:00:00 PM**, the result is the same ***"2012-04-27 06:00:00.000"***

Comment: Side-note: this has nothing to do with WPF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've used `hh` which uses the 12-hour clock. You want `HH` which uses the 24-hour clock.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details about custom format strings.

Note that you may wish to specify the invariant culture, unless you really want the time separator to depend on the current culture:

```
string formatted = StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(Note that you shouldn't have the braces if you're passing the format string to `ToString`. I'll assume this was just a typo in the question.)

If you *want* to use the 12-hour clock, use `tt` in the format string to produce the AM/PM designator.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that worked for me. I do not wish to pass the CultureInfo as I am not showing this date on the UI, but instead passing it as a parameter to SSRS that uses it in executing the stored proc. Yes, braces were a typo, I will correct it. I am just disappointed that there is no native DateTimePicker control in WPF as of now.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh: The whole point of explicitly passing in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is to *avoid* using the current user-specific culture.